# Help! How to get my baby pigeon to eat?

Tags: birds

Yesterday, I found a baby pigeon by the highway. It was pushing itself under vehicles, so I got it home. I gave it water to drink, but it is not eating. I tried to feed it Bajra (pearl millet). It was defecating properly earlier, now it's more like urinating. Please answer urgently for I fear it will not live long without food. It has its left leg, which moves, and has no visible injury, but it limps. It allows me to touch it, and pet it, lift it, and once voluntarily came and sat on my thigh.

Comment: I am no expert, so this as a comment: Website about baby bird rescue (feeding in the bottom half): https://pethelpful.com/wildlife/Helping-Wildlife-What-to-Do-When-You-Find-a-Baby-Bird

Answer (score 0):

If the bird is not eating by itself, you should probably syringe-feed it. I remember a pigeon rescue that I did myself. The bird had a broken wing, and we named her Hope, as in we hoped the bird would heal. That bird had the same problem, a lots of syringe feedings later and a healed wing later, Hope was released back into the wild (only to be killed by a car seconds after).

But if you really are concerned for the life of this bird, I'd say a vet would be your best option. Another thing I should mention is syringe feeding may stress the bird out, and so only do that if the bird won't eat by itself. Also, you need to make sure the bird doesn't become reliant on you for food, or else it may not do well once you release. If you plan on keeping it for a pet, make sure you know what you're doing before you try anything, for example, you wouldn't adopt a dog without having any dog food or the proper equipment (leash, kennel, bed etc.) so why would you adopt a bird without anything?

As for the pooping issue, there are so many different variables and possibilities there that I can't even begin to give you a 100% accurate answer. First off, bird poop is usually wet/liquid-y when it comes out, but you've got a good eye, my friend, because it should not be like urine. After some research, I found a website that had an article about abnormal droppings. You should probably check it [out.](https://vcahospitals.com/know-your-pet/birds-abnormal-droppings)

Other than that, that's about all I have to say. I pray that your bird will live and that I am not too late.